# GhostScipt - Can resize output image file

Tags: image, pdf, ghostscript

I'm converting pdf to html with help GS 9.04.

But in result i'm getting big file and it's ok for printing purpose.
But for monitor screen i would like to have the same quality but smaller size.

Is it possible to make resize by GS and do not loose the quality ?

now i have the next code

```
gs \
 -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT \
 -r300 \
 -sDEVICE=pngmono \
 -dTextAlphaBits=4 \
 -dFirstPage={$page} \
 -dLastPage={$page} \
 -sOutputFile={$filename} \
  {$pdf}
```

and output file is good for printing. When i'm using -g option it makes crop.
If i'm adjusting -r value it makes smaller and ugly at the same moment.

What i want to get is smaller image suitable and readable to looking on it via screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lower resolution which will generate a smaller output file. The fact that you prefer the high resolution image suggest that there is some kind of anti-aliasing or other image manipulation being performed on the image, Ghostscript can do this, by using 'interpolation' but its not really what its good at.

Ideally you would do this with an image manipulation package, but you can try the tiffscaled devices (on gs 9.04) to get an idea of what can be done. Personally I would suggest you use something like imagemagick to do the resolution reduction.

Comment: if i'm making lower resolution text become hard readable :( If i'm using convert from Imagemagick it reduce resolution more than 2-3 sec.
from file 
`PNG 3508x2480 3508x2480+0+0 8-bit PseudoClass 2c 52.8KB 0.000u 0:00.009`

Comment: `# convert -verbose -thumbnail 900 big.png small.png  big.png PNG 3508x2480 3508x2480+0+0 8-bit PseudoClass 2c 52.8KB 0.240u 0:00.140  
big.png=>small.png PNG 3508x2480=>900x636 8-bit DirectClass 49.2KB 2.250u 0:02.389
`

Comment: I can't offer any help with imagemagick, I don't know the package.

Comment: I'm not asking help with imagemagick. I'm asking about ghostscript. And my question can I make output image smaller dimension then input pdf, without loos so much quality ? Now i can make it with help -r option but in this case text become ugly. But i would like to keep as much as possible text view, and set dimension manually, is it possible ?

Comment: Try the tiffscaled device, as I suggetsed above.

Comment: Ok, I've tried and result the next - Only with lzw compression output tiff file has similar size. Tiff - 22Kb, Png - 15Kb. With other type of compression or without it at all result tiff file has bigger size till 150 Kb. Gs makes tiff files slower, really slower maybe for 1 sec sure. And the main problem if -r smaleer 150 text fonts looks no so much readable. Maybe the main problem in pdf ? Actually in the world there are a lot of pictures with smaller resolution and good fonts.. i don't know what the reason :(

Comment: The point was the quality. tiffsclaed works by rendering to a higher resolution and then applying filters to downsample to a lower resolution. The same technique *could* be applied to the png device.  This is a simple matter of programming.  But if you don't like the quality, there is no point in approaching that as a solution.  Of course, the fact that you render at a higher resolution and then downsample means it *will* be slower.  Its up to you to decide what is importnat to you.

Comment: I just want to know is there any possibility to have usual screen size image with normal readable text ? from "invoice like" pdf file. Or it's not possible ?

Comment: It depends totally on the context. What resolution is the 'screen', what point size is the text ? What size is the original and what scale factor is applied when drawn on screen ? Is it high contrast (black on white) or low ? All these factors, and others, affect the readability.

Comment: do you know how invoice looks like ? white paper with black color text and tables, and nothing more. And this "invoice" in pdf has 300 dpi. and A4 paper size. And when i'm making image from that pdf, it can be readable nice only if -r has more than 150, in all other cases fonts looks like ugly (not smooth). And my main question what gs option i can use to make image smaller but keep readable (exclude -r option).

Comment: Your comment about what an invoice looks like is irrelevant, somewhat rude and inaccurate. I have a number of invoices in front of me containing colour and image. You say your 'PDF has 300 dpi', which is unlikely as PDF is usually resolution independent. However its contents may be limited to a bitmap image in which case there are other problems which might apply. I cannot possibly give you a correct set of gs controls without knowing a great deal more than you have given me. If you're not prepared to share an example file then we may as well terminate this conversation.

Comment: I can share it's not a big deal. Could i send it to you by email? or write me your email addres to this email box - poidet _AT_ gmail *dot* com

Thanks

Comment: Send it to ken at spamcop dot net and I'll take a look.